# Matrix Table - Date Columns, location rows and count days at location for date

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, date-range

I am looking to create a series of matrix tables in a Power BI Report.

The data we have is:

```
EventID|VehicleID|LocationID|StartDate|EndDate
1      |1        |GBR       |2010-1-1 |2010-1-5
2      |9        |RUS       |2010-1-3 |2010-1-7
3      |6        |GBR       |2010-1-3 |2010-1-5
4      |1        |USA       |2010-1-5 |2010-1-7
```

Output

```
    LocationID 2010-1-1|2010-1-2|2010-1-3|2010-1-4|2010-1-5|2010-1-6
GBR               1    |   1    |     2  |     2  |   0    |    0
USA               0    |   0    |     0  |     0  |   1    |    1
RUS               0    |   0    |     1  |     1  |   1    |    1
```

Each vehicle only has one the event within a time period there are no overlaps of time for each vehicle. We are trying to get counts of the number of vehicles at each location for each date e.g. If there are 4 vehicles on the 1st of January for LocationID we show 4 in the 4 matrix cell.

I have created a Date Table in our SQL Server (we are using Direct Query) but am really struggling how to get a count of the number of vehicles at each Location per day. I assume I have to in some way convert the date range for each event to a list of the dates for the event and have an item count of 1 for days for each of those. Then I just need to create the Matrix with columns as Date from date table and locationID from event table but how I get the count of locationIDS is eluding me. Any ideas?

Comment: I can do this by creating a view in SQL Server that splits out the event into many rows one per day in the date range and then import that into PowerBI. However, we are trying to avoid creating Views in SQL Server (as we have hundreds to manage). I'd prefer a pure PowerBI solution - as well so I can understand how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample data set and expected result?

Comment: @FoxanNg Sorry about that - added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new table with DAX based on the `StartDate` and `EndDate`:

```
Date = CALENDAR(MIN(Event[StartDate]), MAX(Event[EndDate]))
```

[image: date]

And build the `Count` Measure by comparing the date with `StartDate` and `EndDate` and count the number of rows:

```
Count = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Event,
        Event[StartDate] <= MAX('Date'[Date]) &&
        Event[EndDate] > MIN('Date'[Date])
    )
) + 0
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: I don't think I can create tables with DirectQuery to SQL Server?

Comment: Also if I use the SQL server date table with your measure I seem to get the wrong numbers. I seem to need to use Count = 
SUMX(
FILTER(
        Event,
        Event[StartDate] <= MAX('Date'[Date]) &&
        Event[EndDate] > MIN('Date'[Date])
    )
,(DATEDIFF( Event[StartDate] , Event[EndDate] ,DAY)+1)) + 0 otherwise I  think I just get count of events of that type rather than total number of days in period.

Comment: @GraemeMiller You don't need to create the Date table if you already have an existing date table. It's just for demo purpose.